# SSRS RDL File - Can I embed a string that won't be removed by the designer

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I need to put a hidden checksum (encrypted string) inside a report rdl file but I everything I try gets removed by the designer.

I was wondering if there's a way to stop the designer doing this for say XML comments or perhaps something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a hidden textbox on the report and setting the value expression to the checksum?